# Windows Service C# get list of process

Tags: c#, windows, process, windows-services

i'm coding a simple windows service in c#.
I want to get the list of process on my computer, and "kill" another program i already made with windows form. In particular I want to kill that program when it reach 300MB of memory consumption.

```
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            String path = @"C:\\tmp\\" + theprocess.ProcessName;
            File.Create(path);
        }
```

with this code i get only 3 processes: conhost, devenv, svchost.
I want to get all the list of processes that I can see with the task manager.
somebody can help me?
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Which account do you have the service running under?

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to get the single process you want to kill then? Could do this by calling `Process.GetProcessesByName`.

Comment: @itsme86 LocalSystem

Comment: You can try running the PowerShell command 'ps' to get the data for all running processes, try having a look here "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/" or you can try to access the services from ServiceController.GetServices  :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a(v=vs.110).aspx      I Hope this helps !